# Display object values

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have created an object `person` and created 2 properties for that `person` object in JavaScript. I passed data to that object as:

```
personA = new person("Michel","Newyork"); 
personB = new person("Roy","Miami");
```

What I need is, how to display both `personA` & `personB` values at same time through JavaScript?

Comment: Where do you want to display the values? And what do you mean by "at the same time"?

Comment: What does the `person` constructor take? What property does it assign too?

Comment: Show us the code for `person`!

Comment: For display object value Please refer this link http://technologiessolution.blogspot.in/2013/11/how-to-print-content-of-javascript.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume `person` takes a `name` and `loc` (for location) since you didn't clarify:

```
var personArr = []; //create a person array
//Then push our people
personArr.push(personA);
personArr.push(personB);
for (var i = 0; i < personArr.length; i++) {
   console.log(personArr[i].name);
   console.log(personArr[i].loc);
}
```

If you're talking about literally at the same time, I won't say it's impossible, just not possible with JavaScript unless you use WebWorkers and those don't fair too well in IE.

Comment: Not a problem! If it helped, would you mind selecting the answer as selected?

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to display them on the console,for debug purposes, use

```
 console.log (personA, personB);
```

If you want to alert them to the screen :

```
 alert (JSON.stringify (personA), JSON.stringify (personB));
```

If you want to change a DOM element to contain the values :

```
 domElement.innerHTML = personA.name + ' from ' + personA.loc + ' and ' +
                        personB.name + ' from ' + personB.loc;
```

assuming here than `name` and `loc` are the property names you used.

Of course you can use any of these methods in any context depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider this approach:

```
var persons = {
    person: [],

    add: function(name, city)
    {
        this.person.push({
            'name': name,
            'city': city
        });
    }

};

persons.add("Michael", "New York");
persons.add("Roy", "Miami");
```

Output:

```
for(x in persons.person)
{
    console.log(x + ":");

    for(y in persons.person[x])
    {
        console.log(y + ": " + persons.person[x][y]);
    }
}

------

0:
name: Michael
city: New York
1:
name: Roy
city: Miami
```